# Javac exclusion of package in ANT build.xml

Tags: web-services, ant, javac

I'm trying to compile all my packages except two of them, here is what my javac in build.xml looks like

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${output}" debug="${debug}" failonerror="yes" >
    <exclude name="com/abc/uyyy/**"/>
    <exclude name="com/abc/zzz/**"/>
    <include name="com/abc/zzz/Text.java"/>
    <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.abc"/>
    <classpath refid="abc.module.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

But all the files in package are compiled :(.

I've read the documentation (`http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html`), but still no success, any help?

NOTE: After the Text.java is compiled, I need to build the WSDL file and then build the excluded packages. I'm using Metro to write and build my WS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is what I did,I wrote a new target to compile only the WS file and then generate the classes, it works fine :)

```
<target name="compile-ws-server">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${output}"
        debug="${debug}" failonerror="yes">
            <include name="com/abc/xxx/Text.java"/>
            <exclude name="${src}/abc/xxx/**"/>
            <classpath refid="abc.module.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it not possbile to compile all the class files into one directory, then use the copy task like below to only copy the ones you want for WSDL?

```
<target name="copy_all_class_files">
    <copy todir="${output}">
        <fileset dir="classes">
            <include name="com/abc/zzz/Text.class"/>
            <exclude name="com/abc/uyyy/**"/>
            <exclude name="com/abc/zzz/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling itself. Only after I'm able to compile can I generate the WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

All Above is not proper way ...

I have done like

```
<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" excludes="com/company/example/test/**" />
</target>
```

Here we should avoid placing ${src} and start from inside src folder.